# compilation variants for firebase in android studio (productFlavors)

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to make compilation variants for `firebase`, where I have two folders one prd and another qas in each folder are the `google-services.json`. But it shows me the error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processQasDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute provider#com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider@authorities value=(com.it.mobile.hansa.hbm.firebaseinitprovider) from AndroidManifest.xml:276:13-79
>       is also present at [com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.8.0] AndroidManifest.xml:10:13-72 value=(com.it.mobile.hansa.hbm.qas.firebaseinitprovider).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:authorities"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:274:9-278:39 to override.

This is my gradle module:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.it.mobile.hansa.hbm"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {
        qas {
            applicationId 'com.it.mobile.hansa.hbm.qas'
        }
        prd {
            applicationId 'com.it.mobile.hansa.hbm'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':horizontalcalendar')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

[image]

Comment: Where is your line that applies the google services plugin?

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: *Where* is it in your build.gradle?  You're not showing the entire file. Please edit the question to show that.

Comment: Please share us the entire `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Lo solucione copiando el json a cada carpeta QAS y PRD tambien en los Debug y Release de cada flavor